# Confusion about Installation Requisite for TensorFlow

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, anaconda

I am now maintaining a legacy project which utilizes `tensorflow-gpu-1.11`. According to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu), this package is associated with some particular versions of `gcc`, CUDA, and cuDNN

```
Version                 Python version  Compiler    Build tools     cuDNN   CUDA
...
tensorflow_gpu-1.11.0   2.7, 3.3-3.6    GCC 4.8     Bazel 0.15.0    7       9
...
```

Therefore, I think I need to

- Step 1: set up system compiler to `gcc-4.8`, perhaps using `sudo update-alternatives --config ...`
- Step 2: install CUDA 9.0 and associated cuDNN 7
- Step 3: creates a virtual environment and `pip install tensorflow_gpu==1.11.0`

However, an alternative way to install this package is by invoking following command in the `conda` environment

```sh
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu=1.11.0
```

which, **contrary to the official requirement**, tries to install higher versions of `cudatoolkit` and `cudnn`, as shown below

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
...
  cudatoolkit        anaconda/linux-64::cudatoolkit-9.2-0
  cudnn              anaconda/linux-64::cudnn-7.2.1-cuda9.2_0
...
  tensorflow         anaconda/linux-64::tensorflow-1.11.0-gpu_py36h9c9050a_0
  tensorflow-base    anaconda/linux-64::tensorflow-base-1.11.0-gpu_py36had579c0_0
  tensorflow-gpu     anaconda/linux-64::tensorflow-gpu-1.11.0-h0d30ee6_0
...
```

I am not sure if I understand the installation requirements correctly. If not, hope someone could help on the right track.

Comment: The requirements do not seem to specify the minor version. `9 != 9.0`

Comment: The link your looking at is for building TensorFlow from source. You don't need to build TensorFlow from source, so you don't need gcc. The version of CUDA and CuDNN that Anaconda wants to install is correct.